# Sproutcore: Text not displayed in LabelView

Tags: javascript, label, sproutcore

The following is where `LabelView` is defined. Whatver is being is set as its value is also displayed in an alert box on clicking it. However only the alert box shows the output.:

```
    outputView: SC.LabelView.design({
          layout: { width: 500, height: 18 }, 
          valueBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('Tree.categoriesControllerList.selection.content'),
          click: function(){ 
             alert(Tree.categoriesControllerList.getPath('selection.firstObject.content'))
          }})
```

The `value` of the label is not being set for some reason. The value given is `viewUpdate`, defined as follows:

```
viewUpdate: function(){         
          if (this.didChangeFor('selectionDidChange', selection')&&this.getPath('selection.firstObject.notes')==null){
                    return this.getPath('selection.firstObject.content')
            }
        }.property()
```

I'm certain that this is returning the right value because whenever I click on the label, its value appears in the alert box as instructed.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forget "firstObject" in the value binding:

```
valueBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('Tree.categoriesControllerList.selection.firstObject.content'),
```

Comment: Haha. Yeah. My bad. Thanks for pointing it out. I'm quite new to this and seem to have been making a lot of these silly errors.